# Mysql where query... select * where field1 +field2 + field3 <= field 4

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

Basically I want to add up the numbers stored in `field1`, `field2` and `field3` and only display records that this total is less than `field4`...

For example: `select * from table where field1 + field2 + field3 <= field 4`

But that doesnt work....any help appreciated

here is my actual SQL as you can see its more complex:

```
SELECT
  *,
  SUM ( amountpaid , amountpaid2 , amountpaid3 ) AS total AND
  DATE_FORMAT(date_start, ' %d.%m.%Y') AS date_formatted
FROM 
  calendar_event 
WHERE 
  Date_start BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND 
  total <= amount )
```

Rob

Comment: That should work just fine assuming all fields are numeric (and not null)

Comment: Your code includes three errors: 1) `AND` in the select expression is not valid syntax. 2) You can't mix `SUM()`, an aggregate function, with non-aggregated columns. 3) There is no such syntax as `SUM(a, b, c)`. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: here is my code: SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date_start, ' %d.%m.%Y') AS date_formatted
FROM calendar_event WHERE Date_start BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND amountpaid + amountpaid2 + amountpaid3  <= amount )  i want to display only records where date is within 14 days, and where amountpaid, amountpaid2 and amountpaid3 added together are less than  amount

Comment: Looks good, is there an error?

Comment: one question: why didn't you post your query to begin with and stop people from wasting their time?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe what you mean is:

```
SELECT
    *,
    amountpaid + amountpaid2 + amountpaid3 AS total,
    DATE_FORMAT(date_start, '%d.%m.%Y') AS date_formatted
FROM calendar_event
WHERE Date_start BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
AND amountpaid + amountpaid2 + amountpaid3 <= amount
```

Assuming that you have the separate payments in `amountpaid`, `amountpaid2` and `amountpaid3`, this would give you all the events that start in the next 14 days and are not overpaid (i.e. either underpaid or paid exactly).

Answer (score 0):

Your query

```
select * from table where field1 + field2 + field3 <= field4
```

should work totally fine. Make sure all columns you are addressing actually exist and that they are numeric (integer, float, double, etc.). Also make sure, if you actually called it that, that field4 has no space between "field" and "4" - there is a space between in your question, like "field 4" instead of "field4".

Alternatively let us know what error message you get.

Comment: here is my actual query: SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date_start, ' %d.%m.%Y') AS date_formatted
FROM calendar_event WHERE Date_start BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND amountpaid + amountpaid2 + amountpaid3  <= amount )

Comment: amountpaid, amountpaid2 and amountpaid3 are all int but im getting Warning: mysql_numrows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in...

Comment: That only means that the query failed. Run the query in phpmyadmin and tell us what the error message is there.

Comment: )
ORDER BY date_start ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
MySQL said: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')

ORDER BY date_start ASC 
LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2

Comment: There was no order clause in the statement that you said was your full statement. Please post the entire query. There seems to be a syntax error in the order by clause, apparently one opening parenthesis too many?

Comment: thanks charles... sorted now works with: "SELECT * , DATE_FORMAT( date_start,  ' %d.%m.%Y' ) AS date_formatted
FROM calendar_event
WHERE Date_start
BETWEEN NOW( ) 
AND DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 14 
DAY ) 
AND amountpaid + amountpaid2 + amountpaid3 < amount";

Comment: I am glad it works now. Please accept the answer that helped you most by clicking the checkbox on the left.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
  *,
  Coalesce(amountpaid, 0) + Coalesce(amountpaid2, 0) + Coalesce(amountpaid3, 0) As total,
  DATE_FORMAT(date_start, ' %d.%m.%Y') As date_formatted
From
  calendar_event 
Where
  Date_start Between Now() And Date_Add(Now(), Interval 14 DAY) And
  Coalesce(amountpaid, 0) + Coalesce(amountpaid2, 0) + Coalesce(amountpaid3, 0) <= amount
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35f6b/3